# Passing variables to a variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables, quotes

I'm writing custom logging for the bash:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e +x

SCRIPT_LOG_NAME='[MYSCRIPT]'
SCRIPT_LOG_DATETIME_FORMAT="+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
SCRIPT_LOG_LEVEL_INFO='INFO'
SCRIPT_LOG_PATTERN="${SCRIPT_LOG_NAME} $(date "${SCRIPT_LOG_DATETIME_FORMAT}") $1 : $2"

log_general() {
  ...
}

log_info() {
  log_general "$SCRIPT_LOG_LEVEL_INFO" "$1"
}
```

And I want to pass variables `$SCRIPT_LOG_LEVEL_INFO` and `"$1"` as parameters to the function `log_general()`. And use this parameters in the `$SCRIPT_LOG_PATTERN` to achive output: 
`[MYSCRIPT] 2023-01-01 10:10:10 INFO : Something logged`

I tried something like:

```bash
log_general() {
  echo -e "$SCRIPT_LOG_PATTERN" "$1" "$2"
}
```

Or

```bash
SCRIPT_LOG_LEVEL=''
SCRIPT_LOG_PATTERN="${SCRIPT_LOG_NAME} $(date "${SCRIPT_LOG_DATETIME_FORMAT}") ${SCRIPT_LOG_LEVEL} : "

log_general() {
  SCRIPT_LOG_LEVEL=$SCRIPT_LOG_LEVEL_INFO
  echo -e "${SCRIPT_LOG_PATTERN}${1}"
}

log_info() {
  log_general "$1"
}
```

But I could not achieve the desired result. Can you help me, please?

Comment: It does not make sense that you already put in the date when setting SCRIPT_LOG_PATTERN. By doing this you will log the exactly same date every time when calling `log_general`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to use `${SCRIPT_LOG_PATTERN}` as a global variable and later on substitute the `${1}` and `${2}` you would have to escape the `$` sign and then evaluate the string later on in `log_general`.

This would look something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e +x

SCRIPT_LOG_NAME='[MYSCRIPT]'
SCRIPT_LOG_DATETIME_FORMAT="+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
SCRIPT_LOG_LEVEL_INFO='INFO'
SCRIPT_LOG_PATTERN="${SCRIPT_LOG_NAME} $(date "${SCRIPT_LOG_DATETIME_FORMAT}") \$1 : \$2"

log_general() {
        eval echo "${SCRIPT_LOG_PATTERN}"
}

log_info() {
        log_general "${SCRIPT_LOG_LEVEL_INFO}" "${1}"
}
```

Usage:

```
$ source logging_test.sh
$ log_info "my custom message"
[MYSCRIPT] 2023-06-02 14:03:27 INFO : my custom message
```

I'd also recommend escaping the `date` command since otherwise the date will be parsed once, here is what I mean:

```bash
$ log_info "asdads"; sleep 5; log_info "asdsad"
[MYSCRIPT] 2023-06-02 14:06:28 INFO : asdads
[MYSCRIPT] 2023-06-02 14:06:28 INFO : asdsad
```

As you can see the time does not change even with 5 seconds of sleep.

To fix this escape the `date` as well like this:

```bash
SCRIPT_LOG_PATTERN="${SCRIPT_LOG_NAME} \$(date '${SCRIPT_LOG_DATETIME_FORMAT}') \$1 : \$2"
```

Output now:

```bash
$ log_info "asdads"; sleep 5; log_info "asdsad"
[MYSCRIPT] 2023-06-02 14:09:19 INFO : asdads
[MYSCRIPT] 2023-06-02 14:09:25 INFO : asdsad
```

Comment: A while back I created a small logger for bash, maybe it can help you get some idea or help improve your own logger: https://gist.github.com/ArslanSB/92663e81e5128d1fc3b9ef053f08852e

Answer (score 1):

Try `printf`:

```
pattern="%s $(date "${SCRIPT_LOG_DATETIME_FORMAT}") %s : %s"

log_general() {
    printf -v SCRIPT_LOG_PATTERN "$pattern" "$1" "$2" "$3"
}
```

Usage:

```
log_general "$SCRIPT_LOG_NAME" "$1" "$2"
```

This function will set $SCRIPT_LOG_PATTERN variable using $pattern variable, all '%s' will be changed to provided values accordingly.